# How to create an HTML module angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Learning HTML/Angular.

I have a bunch of HTML code that I want to be re-usable. Basically I write it once and modify the same code base, then just insert the dynamic data using Angular.

My question is - How do I create re-usable HTML code that can be injected into a page using Angular?

For instance, lets say I am an app developer and want to showcase 25 apps on the same page each with their own HTML component (not just a bunch of images). Rather than copying the HTML 25 times I would just like to inject that HTML snippet via some angular command, then insert the text into the corresponding divs etc. I need to stick with Angular/HTML (no other frameworks)

Or is there a better way?

(look at the image for reference - imagine inserting that layout 25 times without duplicating code)

I have tried this using ng-repeat but when I do so it throws the repeating items in the same spot on top of each other. I was hoping that for every div that is repeated it would put it underneath the other div.

```
<div id="apps" ng-controller="MyApps">
    <div id="appsection" ng-repeat="app in applist">
      <img class="rightappimg" src={{app.img}} />
      <strong class="appbannertext">{{app.firstLine}}</strong>
      <strong class="appbannertextsubtitle">{{app.secondLine}}</strong>
      <strong class="appbannertextsubtitlesmall"><span class="ios">iOS, iPhone, iPad</span> & <span class="android"> Android</span></strong>
      <strong class="appbannerdescriptiontitle">{{app.fourthLine}}</strong>
      <p class="appbannerdescription">{{app.fifthLine}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Overlap]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at ng-repeat?

Comment: I used ng-repeat in the angular google tutorial to insert images. But this seems more complex. It has divs with associated css. I can understand how to repeat the text content and the images, but how do you ng-repeat the entire layout?

Comment: So, each layout is completely different then?  I mean, they don't have common elements like each one has a headline, subhead, description, link and a carousel of screenshots?

Comment: Each will have a headline, description, and image. I think i see what you are saying - you are saying the ng-repeat will repeat the entire block of html code and then insert the appropriate images/text?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking.  Attach the repeat to the container div, then iterate over the array of your objects within the template.  So each object would have something like: [{headline: "Headline here", description: "some description", images: [img1.jpg,img2.jpg]}, ...]

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer was to us ng-repeat as such:

```
<div id="apps" ng-controller="MyApps">
<div id="appsection" ng-repeat="app in applist">
  <img class="rightappimg" src={{app.img}} />
  <strong class="appbannertext">{{app.firstLine}}</strong>
  <strong class="appbannertextsubtitle">{{app.secondLine}}</strong>
  <strong class="appbannertextsubtitlesmall"><span class="ios">iOS, iPhone, iPad</span> & <span class="android"> Android</span></strong>
  <strong class="appbannerdescriptiontitle">{{app.fourthLine}}</strong>
  <p class="appbannerdescription">{{app.fifthLine}}</p>
</div>
```

And then simply to specify a min-height in the div id in the CSS file so the items wouldn't overlap each other.